# dont list files in the mentioned directories

Tags: bash

I have three directories with sub directories the parent directory are a, b, & c. a1&a2 are subdirectories of a, b1&b2 are subdirectories of b, c1&c2 are subdirectories of c. The files are arranged like this format a.txt(a), a1.txt(a1), a2.txt(a2), b.txt(b), b1.txt(b1), b2.txt(b2), c.txt(c), c1.txt(c1), c2.txt(c2). Now I am trying to list the files like i want to ignore the files in the entire directory a with its sub directories a1&a2  and want to igonre the files only in the directory b1  not directory b or b2 and want to ignore the files only in the directory c2 not the directories c or c1.                                       Script which I have tried is below

```
#!/bin/sh
find * -type d | while IFS= read d
do
    dirname=`basename $d`
    if [ ${dirname} != "a" ] || [ ${dirname} != "b1" ] || [ ${dirname} != "c2" ]
 then          
   cd $dirname
          find * ! -name . -prune -type f | while read fname
          do
             fname=`basename $fname`
             echo $fname
          done
        fi 
done
```

The results are of the above script is

```
a.txt
a2.txt
b.sh: a1: does not exist
```

May i know what is the mistake i am doing in it.

Comment: Could you edit your post and present it a bit better? It is very difficult to read it!

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce test

```
mkdir -p {a/a,b/b,c/c}{1,2}
touch {a/a,b/b,c/c}.txt
for d in {a/a,b/b,c/c}{1,2}; do touch $d/${d#*/}.txt; done

find . -type f
./a/a.txt
./a/a1/a1.txt
./a/a2/a2.txt
./b/b.txt
./b/b1/b1.txt
./b/b2/b2.txt
./c/c.txt
./c/c1/c1.txt
./c/c2/c2.txt
```

The find command

```
find . \( -path ./a -o -path ./b/b1 -o -path ./c/c2 \) -prune -o -print
```

Explanation

`-prune` over a directory  will prevent find to descend into it, is applied over condition between escaped parenthesis `-o` equivalent to `-or`, however it returns true on matching files, after the next -o conditions can be added, (by default junction is `-a`, `-and` which can be ommited) and action (`-printf` `-ls` `-exec` etc.).

Other example :

```
find . \( -path ./a -o -path ./b/b1 -o -path ./c/c2 \) -prune -type f -o -type f
./b/b.txt
./b/b2/b2.txt
./c/c.txt
./c/c1/c1.txt
```

EDIT after comment:

```
find . -type d \( -name a -o -name b1 -o -name c2 \) -prune -type f -o -type f -printf '%f\n'
b.txt
b2.txt
c.txt
c1.txt
```

EDIT after last comment (SunOS find doesn't have `-printf`) :

```
find . -type d \( -name a -o -name b1 -o -name c2 \) -prune -o -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do d=${f%/*}; echo "${d##*/}" "${f##*/}"; done' sh-echo {} +
b b.txt
b2 b2.txt
c c.txt
c1 c1.txt
```

Comment: When i execute the above command i got the error as                                     find: bad option -path
And also i would like to list the files in the bare format with only filenames like the below                                                                                                       b.txt                                                                                                                            b1.txt                                                                                                                             b2.txt......

Comment: `-path`is specific gnu find, you can use -name instead but will be less specific, see update

Comment: printf option is not working in my solaris OS, hence i used print and below is the command which is giving the result   find . -type d \( -name a -o -name b1 -o -name c2 \) -prune -o -type f -print    /*  I need to view the result the like (first column)folder name (second column) file name  like b b.txt \n b2 b2.txt  \n c c.txt \n c1 c1.txt

Comment: find . -type d ( -type d -a ( -name a1 -o -name b2 -o -name c3 ) ) -prune -o -type f -print>test.csv   can you guide me how can i display in excel sheet like the below format                                                                                Folders Files                                                                                                   b b.txt